# NW.JS + Typescript - Не выводит в консоль

Tags: typescript, nw.js

Точка входа приложения nw.js - index.html
В этом **index.html** я подключаю фаил **main.js**

Если подключаю так (**вариант 1**):

```
<script>
  console.log("I'am index.html") // это - ВЫВОДИТСЯ в консоль успешно в ОБОИХ случаях!
  var test = require('main.js'); // НЕ выводит в консоль то что в main.js
</script>
```

то **НЕ выводит** в консоль то что указано в main.js **НО** остальной код в main.js (а именно импорт) работает нормально.

Если подключаю так (**вариант 2**):

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log("I'am index.html") // это - ВЫВОДИТСЯ в консоль успешно в ОБОИХ случаях!
</script>
```

то **успешно выводится** в консоль то, что указано в main.js, **НО** перестаёт работать импорт:
(Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at main.js:7)

**Как мне добиться того, чтобы работало всё как в ПЕРВОМ варианте НО работала консоль**
*(выводилось в консоль "I'am main.ts" например)*

NW.JS установлен такой: nwjs-sdk-v0.46.3-win-x64 (с инструментами, с оф сайта, как положено)

**main.js** (результат компиляции main.ts):

```
exports.__esModule = true; // это строка 7 если что (во втором случае стопорится здесь, но за то работает консоль)
var Eating_1 = require("./Modules/Eating");
var Test = new Eating_1.Eating(); // в первом случае успешно отрабатывает кроме консоли (строкИ ниже)
console.log("I'am main.ts"); // в первом случае это НЕ выводится в консоль (ни ошибок, ничего) !!!
```

**main.ts**

```
import { Eating } from "./Modules/Eating"

let Test = new Eating() // в первом случае успешно отрабатывает кроме консоли (строкИ ниже)
console.log("I'am main.ts") // в первом случае это НЕ выводится в консоль (ни ошибок, ничего) !!!
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "dia-js",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.22" 
  }
}
```

Мучаюсь почти целый день... Помогите!!!

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript

Comment: nw.js как я понял вы не рекомендуете использовать?

Comment: Команда TS разработала VSCode который основан на Electron. А рекомендую я использовать то что 1 работает 2вам нравится